# Checking Nulls or Empty

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
ID   Item.  Price.  Rating  Location
-------------------------------------
1    abc     2               xyz
2.   milk   10        7
3.   rose                    qqq
4.   DVD    10        2        
5.   WQQ     5
```

I have to output the result of all the items into good or bad, good item is where Price and Location column is not null or empty.

Output

```
Good  Bad
1     4
```

How to do that in single query?

Comment: What do you mean with "empty"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following with `case` expression. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2e1tRAxJJh9isPDYjzk9i1/0).

```
select
  sum(case when price is not null and location is not null then 1 else 0 end) as good,
  sum(case when price is null or location is null then 1 else 0 end) as bad
from yourTable
```

Output:

```
| good | bad |
| ---- | --- |
| 1    | 4   |
```

Comment: That's case _expressions_, not statements. (A case expression returns a value. A case statement is used for conditional execution of code in stored procedures.)

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the feedback and I have updated my answer.